# toSharedViewController not re-using existing controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

My URL map is as follows:

```
[map from:@"tt://webPage/(initWithPage:)" toSharedViewController:[WebPageController class]];
```

and in the `WebPageController`

```
- (id) initWithPage:(WebPage)page
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
    ...
```

Then I called the url several times in my code

```
tt://webPage/1
tt://webPage/2
tt://webPage/1 (still called the initWithPage: everytime, not cached)
```

Why it is not cached as it is a SharedViewController?

Comment: What is `WebPage` typedefed to?

Comment: @tonklon, it is just a random ENUM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is happening to you because `TTNaviagtor` is broken on iOS 5. see https://github.com/facebook/three20/pull/719/files. Have you tried running the same code on a iOS 4 with the same result?

My recommendation to you is to stop using `TTNaviagtor`. You can still use the three20 library by pushing and poping `TTViewController` in the native ios method.

Here's an example on replacing the `TTNaviagtor` in your app delegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

 UIWindow* _window;
 TTBaseNavigationController* _masterNavController;
 WebPageController* _web1Controller;
 WebPageController* _web2Controller;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIWindow* window;
@property(nonatomic, retain) TTBaseNavigationController* masterNavController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) WebPageController* web1Controller;
@property(nonatomic, retain) WebPageController* web2Controller;
```

And

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize masterNavController = _masterNavController;
@synthesize web1Controller = _web1Controller;
@synthesize web2Controller = web2Controller;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:TTScreenBounds()];


    TTViewController* controller = [[[MasterViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    _masterNavController = [[TTBaseNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [_window addSubview:_masterNavController.view];    
  }

  [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

then you can push and pop any `TTViewController` (or your own subclasses of `TTViewController`) into the `_masterNavController`. Personally, i think TTNavigator is a bad design pattern, and apple designed their navigation system in different mindset.

Answer (score 0):

why not step into the code and check what happen?

I believe the objects are created in TTURLMap's `objectForURL:query:pattern:` you can set a break point and see why a new one is created instead re-use old one.

this the implementation of `objectForURL:query:pattern:` with my comment

```
- (id)objectForURL: (NSString*)URL
             query: (NSDictionary*)query
           pattern: (TTURLNavigatorPattern**)outPattern {
  id object = nil;
  if (_objectMappings) {
    // _objectMappings is a NSMutableDictionary and use to cache shared object
    object = [_objectMappings objectForKey:URL]; 
    // if object not found than check does _objectMappings contains it with right key
    if (object && !outPattern) {
      return object;
    }
  }

  NSURL* theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
  TTURLNavigatorPattern* pattern  = [self matchObjectPattern:theURL];
  if (pattern) {
    if (!object) {
      // object is not found in the mapping dictionary so create new one, this should only happen once for shared object
      object = [pattern createObjectFromURL:theURL query:query]; 
    }
    // make sure navigationMode is TTNavigationModeShare
    if (pattern.navigationMode == TTNavigationModeShare && object) {
       // cache shared object in the mapping dictionary so next time it will re-use the cached one
      [self setObject:object forURL:URL];
      // if setObject:forURL: is not working than the shared object will not be cached
    }
    if (outPattern) {
      *outPattern = pattern;
    }
    return object;

  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}
```